# Why is my output blank even though nothing in my code is wrong?

Tags: c#

I am confused. When I write the following code, and start the program up, it just shows a blank output. I read online what the problem could be and the most people seem to agree that it's a problem in my code after all, but I cant see where I messed up:

sorry forgot to put the details guys. This is the assignment and the different input/outputs etc:

You and your colleagues are huge fans of your local football team. You therefore often show up to support your team. When your team has made at least ten perfect passes to each other, you give each other one "high five" and "cheers". At more than one and up to ten passes, cheer in "huh!" for each delivery. If your team scores a goal break out in "Olé olé olé". If you have zero submissions, you are silent and say "Shhh". Your boss is so excited about the way you support your team. Therefore you will be tasked to make a program that can run your logic, so that other colleagues can join next time there is local showdown.

TASK

Based on the number of passes played, which your local team has managed, the following applies:

• "High Five - Cheers!!!" for 10 submissions and above,

• "Shh" for less than 1 delivery

• or a string that has "Huh!" for each pass played.

• If your dream team scores a goal, print ONLY "Olé olé olé".

Requirements for Input

The program takes two inputs, an int and string value. The first value represents number submissions and the next value takes the text "target" as input value.

Targets must be able to be written in CAPITAL or lowercase letters, or in one or more capital and small letters letters.

Output

A string that suits your cheering level

Ex 1 on input

5
Goal
Ex 1 on output

Olé olé olé
Ex 2 on input

3
string.Empty;
Ex 2 on output

Huh! Huh! Huh!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyProjectFodbold
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 1;
            int Passes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            string GoalCheck = Console.ReadLine();
            string Goal = "Goal";
            string Output1;


            if (Goal.Equals(GoalCheck, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Olé olé olé");
            }
            else if (Passes == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Shhh.");
            }
            else if (Passes > 9)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("High Five - Cheers!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                Output1 = "Huh! ";
                while (i < Passes)
                {
                    Output1 = Output1 + "Huh! ";
                    i = i + 1;
                }
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope someone can give me some insight on this problem

I have tried looking for the problem but no luck

Comment: What inputs are you giving, The console is waiting for an input on `Console.ReadLine()`

Comment: "even though nothing in my code is wrong?" - this is the first mistake. Always *assume* that the problem is most likely to be in your code. It may not be, but usually it will be. That's not about you, that's just the way life is. If you start with the assumption that the problem *isn't* in your code, it deters you from examining your code properly. Now, it's hard to help at the moment as we've no idea what your code is meant to do. If you type in (say) 5 (press return) and then Goal (press return) then you *do* get output.

Comment: I would note that in your final block, however, you initialize `Output1` and modify it in a loop... but never display it. Perhaps that's the mistake? As an aside, I'd also very strongly recommend that you learn about and start following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: What Jon sais plus: If you expect the user to _input_ something, it is commonly accepted to be a good idea to _tell him what he is expected to do_ before.

Comment: have you put the debugging point in your code to check the procedure?

Comment: If the result of the code does not meet the expected result, then **the code is wrong**, don't try to persuade yourself differently :-)

Answer (score 1):

The implementation is not very solid, but i can see you are in the learning phase, so here there are some comments:

I would strongly recommend avoiding `Convert` without having a `try catch` because it can generate an exception if the input is not correct, so i would do something like this:

```
 bool isInputValid = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int Passes);
```

And after that it would be great if you validate the inputs from your user, using some extra logic.

The problem with your implementation is that it is not clear what is required, so i suggest to write to the console some help messages:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Insert number of Passes");
        bool isInputValid = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int Passes);
        Console.WriteLine("Write goal Check");
        string GoalCheck = Console.ReadLine();
```

And delete the `Console.ReadLine()` after your While loop, instead just write it in the last line of your code.